# Speed up a delta filter in python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, cumsum

I am writing a decompressor which (among other things) has to apply a delta filter to RGB images. That is, read images where only the first pixel is absolute (R1, G1, B1) and all the others are in the form (R[n]-R[n-1], G[n]-G[n-1], B[n]-B[n-1]), and convert them to standard RGB.

Right now I am using numpy as follows:

```
rgb = numpy.fromstring(data, 'uint8')
components = rgb.reshape(3, -1, order='F')
filtered = numpy.cumsum(components, dtype='uint8', axis=1)
frame = numpy.reshape(filtered, -1, order='F')
```

Where

- line 1 creates a 1D array of the original image;
- line 2 reshapes it in the form

  ```
  [[R1, R2, ..., Rn], [G1, G2, ..., Gn], [B1, B2, ..., Bn]]
  ```
- line 3 performs the actual defiltering
- line 4 converts back again to a 1D array

The problem is that it is too slow for my needs. I profiled it and found out that a good amount of time is spent reshaping the array.

So I wonder: is there some way of avoiding reshaping or to speed it up?

Notes:

- I'd prefer not to have to write a C extension for this.
- I'm already using multithreading

Comment: If your `rgb` data ranges from 0 to 255, there is a good chance that `numpy.cumsum` will silently overflow. Take a look at what happens when `x = np.arange(255,dtype = 'uint8')` and `y = np.cumsum(x, dtype = 'uint8')`.

Comment: Well, I think it has to overflow, or to put in another way, it's operating mod 255.

Comment: Oops, so it was intentional. But still, shouldn't it be `filtered = numpy.diff(components, axis = 1)` to compute `R[n]-R[n-1]`, etc.?

Comment: Something like this (actually I'm using numpy.ediff1d) is in the compressor, this is the decompressor which does exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you read it in you can tell it a little more about the type, Try:

```
rgb = numpy.fromstring(data, '3uint8')
```

No reshape needed.

Next, for large operations, where you can get away with it (and `cumsum` qualifies), use the `out=` param to keep from moving the data...everything happens in place. Use:

```
rgb.cumsum(axis=0,out=rgb)
```

if you still want it flattened:

```
rgb = rgb.ravel()
```

Comment: This improved total speed by about 15%, thanks! I'm very near to the point where 3 cores are enough (which is my target).

Comment: After some other experiments, I found out that with this layout it is no more necessary to flatten it. Removing rgb.ravel() produced another +5%!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I did not understand yet, the final reshape in your code copies the data.  This can be avoided by using C order instead of Fortran order:

```
rgb = numpy.fromstring(data, 'uint8')
components = rgb.reshape(-1, 3)
filtered = numpy.cumsum(components, dtype='uint8', axis=0)
frame = filtered.reshape(-1)
```

Comment: Could you show under what circumstance the final reshape copies the data? I wasn't able to see this result myself starting with `rgb = np.fromstring('\x01\x02\x03'*2, dtype=np.uint8)` and looking at `frame.flags['OWNDATA']`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it improved speed by about 12%.

Comment: @unutbu: I found that merely looking at the `owndata` flag isn't a reliable way to find out whether a copy had been made somewhere in between.  I did `frame[:] = 0` and checked if `filtered` was also zeroed, but it wasn't.